# How to decrease the vertical space between the text and the equations?

Tags: spacing

Decrease the vertical space between the text and the equations?

```
Los pesos sinápticos se actualizan de la siguiente manera:

\begin{align*}
    w_1 = 1.6 - 1x0 = 1.6 \\                                                                                                               
w_2 = 2.5 - 1x0 = 2.5  \\                                                                                                               
w_0 = 4.3 - 1x1 = 3.3  \\                                                                                                               
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: And the blank lines inside align.

Comment: And remove the third and final \\ (double backslash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make two changes:

- Remove the blank line *above* the `align*` environment.

  You can remove the blank line below the `\align*` environment as well. However, that decision should depend mostly on whether or not you want the subsequent material to be part of a new (logical) paragraph. The screenshot you posted makes it look like no new paragraph should be started; if that's the case, by all means don't leave any blank lines between the end of the `align*` environment and the subsequent material.
- Remove the `\\` (double backslash) at the end of the final line of the `align*` environment.

A before-and-after comparison:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\setlength\parindent{1em}
\hrule
Los pesos sinápticos se actualizan de la siguiente manera:

\begin{align*}
w_1 = 1.6 - 1x_0 = 1.6 \\                                                                                                               
w_2 = 2.5 - 1x_0 = 2.5  \\                                                                                                               
w_0 = 4.3 - 1x_1 = 3.3  \\                                                                                                               
\end{align*}

Los pesos sinápticos se actualizan de la siguiente manera:
\hrule
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\setlength\parindent{1em}
\hrule
Los pesos sinápticos se actualizan de la siguiente manera: % no blank line next
\begin{align*}
w_1 = 1.6 - 1x_0 = 1.6 \\                                                                                                               
w_2 = 2.5 - 1x_0 = 2.5  \\                                                                                                               
w_0 = 4.3 - 1x_1 = 3.3   % no "\\"                                                                                                         
\end{align*}

Los pesos sinápticos se actualizan de la siguiente manera:
\hrule
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```